# Modeling based on a reference image

Tags: modeling

I'm learning modeling from video tutorials. I need help and good and strong tips that need to create my reference model not this any model I make. I take the reference image and in the properties panel of the 3D view, I adjust the setting side view top bottom extra. Then I take a cube and start drawing with the vertex and loop cut and subsurface modifier.

[image]

I make the side view good way, but when I start making the other view it confuses me and my model looks odd or shapeless. I have attached my model that I made in side view, but when I come to the front view and start matching as I did with the side view its getting shapeless. Can I get strong, good tips on how to make an accurate model from a reference image.

Here is my blend file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your blend files [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). I moved it for you this time.

Comment: yes sorry the page was not loading so i have attached from google drive thanks for uploading

Comment: Start by creating the basic rough shape first in all views with just a few subdivisions. For curved surfaces like this try using proportional editing.  Then increase the level of detail by adding subdivisions and loop cuts.

Answer (score -1):

I cant see your reference image. If you want to pack the image with the .blend file, you need to go to 
File > External data (at the bottom) > and choose "Pack all into .blend

This will stick the images into the blend file for others to see.

Now you question seems a little vague, you seem to be on the right track. There is nothing inherently wrong with your model. Stick a mirror modifier on there and keep working and you'll be done in no time.

If you don't like how your model looks compared to the image, look at the image and say, "How is my model different?" Then change it.